# Function does not work embedded in another function

Tags: r, unique, plyr, distinct-values

in my dataset are IDs with more than only one distinct name. To detect them I buil this function:

```
ddply(my_dataframe, ~ID_col, summarise, number_of_names = length(unique(names_col)))
```

That works just fine, so I get a table with the ID in the first col and it's number of distinct names in the second.

Because I need to do this to several ID/name-pairs I decited to put the ddply-function in a function. I did it as follows:

```
function_name = function (source, id, name) {
  ddply(source, ~id, summarise, number_of_names = length(unique(name)))
```

Unfortunately, this throws an error when I use it:

```
function_name(my_dataframe, ID_col, names_col)
# Error in unique.default(x) : unique() applies only to vectors
```

As you can see, it is the exact same code like before but embedded in a function with three variables. I am desperate about fixing it and really looking forward to a solution.

FYI: 
In my original code I did not use "source" or "name" but German words, so there should be no problems regarding existing other functions. I also already tried to put the variables in quotes.

Thanks for any help!

This is how the DF kinda looks like:

```
my_dataframe <- data.frame(
  ID_col = c(letters[2:9], letters[3:4]),
  names_col = paste0("name-", letters[1:10])
)
```

There are 303 IDs but 963 names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

R has always had the functionality of selecting columns by the value of a variable name by using double square brackets. Using `tapply` you can do it this way:

```
function_name = function (source, id, name) {
    data.frame(
       N=tapply(
           source[[name]],
           my_dataframe[[id]],
           function(x){
             length(unique(x))
             }
          )
        )
  }
```

Then:

```
> function_name(my_dataframe,"ID_col","names_col")
      N
FU181 2
FU901 1
FU992 1
```

Note the names are in the row names of the returned data frame.

Comment: Hi Spacedman,
thanks for that quick response. Works exactly like it should! Also really appreciating, that you used "basic operations". Thus, it is easier for newbies like me to understand what the code is doing!

Answer (score 2):

**1) eval/substitute** Wrap the body in eval.parent(substitute(...)) to cause the arguments to be subsituted in.  The `ddply(...)` line below is identical to that in the question.

```
library(plyr)

function_name = function (source, id, name) eval.parent(substitute(  
  ddply(source, ~id, summarise, number_of_names = length(unique(name))) 
))

function_name(my_dataframe, ID_col, names_col)
```

**2) substitute** This also works and does not rely on `eval`:

```
function_name = function (source, id, name) {
  id <- substitute(id)
  name <- deparse(substitute(name))
  ddply(source, id, function(x) summarise(x, number_of_names = length(unique(x[[name]]))))
}

function_name(my_dataframe, ID_col, names_col)
```

**2a) pass strings** If you are willing to pass character strings it can be shortened to this which is the same as (2) except we omitted the first two lines of the body and we pass character strings when calling it:

```
function_name = function (source, id, name) {
  ddply(source, id, function(x) summarise(x, number_of_names = length(unique(x[[name]]))))
}

function_name(my_dataframe, "ID_col", "names_col")
```

**3) defmacro** Another approach is to create a macro using `defmacro` in gtools.  The `ddply(...)` call is the same as in the question.

```
library(gtools)

macro_name <- defmacro(source, id, name, expr = 
   ddply(source, ~id, summarise, number_of_names = length(unique(name)))
)

macro_name(my_dataframe, ID_col,names_col)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `quosure`s from `dplyr`.  The `enquo` gets the input variable, converts to `quosure`, within the `group_by`, `summarise`, we unquote (`UQ`) the quosure for evaluation

```
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(source, id, name) {
         id <- enquo(id)
         name <- enquo(name)
         source %>%
                group_by(UQ(id)) %>%
                summarise(number_of_names = n_distinct(UQ(name)))
    }

f1(my_dataframe, ID_col, names_col)
# A tibble: 3 x 2 
#   ID_col number_of_names
#   <chr>           <int>
#1  FU181               2
#2  FU901               1
#3  FU992               1
```

NOTE: The solution is based on `dplyr` which is a more advanced version of `plyr`.  The solution takes the input arguments as unquoted, and it can also be modified to take quoted arguments.  The solution can be extended with pipes (`%>%`) and is very flexible

NOTE2: We don't find the `tidyverse` getting messier but in fact it is more clean, consistent when compared to previous solutions with `lazyeval`

#### data

```
my_dataframe <- structure(list(ID_col = c("FU901", "FU992", "FU181", "FU181"), 
names_col = c("take a breath", "use a tissue", "get up", 
"getting up")), .Names = c("ID_col", "names_col"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Comment: Wow. The tidyverse just gets messier and messier. Would a base R solution be acceptable?

Comment: @Spacedman  If you are talking about the lazyeval comparison, it is better

Comment: I get `Error in n_distinct_multi(list(...), na.rm) : is of unsupported type language ` when I run it through my console

Comment: @GregordeCillia  Please check the dplyr version.  I used 0.7.0

Comment: @akrun I have 0.7.1 installed

Comment: there is a version difference, probably a bug in the new version for `n_distinct`

Comment: akrun, also thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am getting an error:
`Error in (function(x, i, exact) if (is.matrix(i)) as.matrix(x)[[i]] else .subset2(x,  : 
  object 'Aktivitaetennummer' not found` 

Aktivitaetennummer = id

Comment: @Torsten  As I showed here, I am not getting any error.  Pleae check your dplyr version

Comment: Ok, easy mistake. Just had to put my variables in quotes... works fine as well!!